# How to get address of each port on usb hub in android

Tags: android, usb, usbserial

I want to connect multiple devices with the android tablet via usb hub and detect each device in order to communicate with it.

I am able to connect more than one non serial devices and differentiate them, but Issue occurs when I want to connect more than one usb serial devices, in this scenario I am unable to differentiate between serial devices and hence cant communicate with them. So I decided to connect device to a dedicated port of usb hub and connect with them. but in order to do this I need to get this info of usb hub.

Is there any way by which I can differentiate each port of usb hub and get their address programmatically.

Here is the link to the related question that I asked earlier which might clear some idea. [How to communicate with more than one USB Serial devices and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37458901/how-to-communicate-with-more-than-one-usb-serial-devices-and-android)